# jTextField validation popup

Tags: java, swing, validation, popup, jtextfield

I want to make a data validation on a Popup
My problem is that I can not check the input if I have made ​​a mistake.

the aim is, if the key.lenght not =0, the popup come.

I know this because I can controle one time my variable key

I do not understand how I could do to be able to control it once in the loop.

thank you

```
    final JFrame popup = new JFrame();
    boolean flag = false;


    String key = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(popup, "Enter key", null);
    char[] var = key.toCharArray();


    while (flag == false) {
        if (key.length() == 1) {
            flag = true;
        } else {
  --->      String popup2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(popup, "Enter key", null);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think popup2 should be key. As i see the code your flag will never be true if it is not first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
key = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(popup, "Enter key", null);
```

instead of

```
String popup2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(popup, "Enter key", null);
```

You are not updating the `key` again.

---

--EDIT--

Try this one also

```
String key = null;
do {
    key = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(popup, "Enter key", null);
} while (key.length() != 1);
```

Comment: basic property of, reason why is here a DocumenLlistener

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry I didn't get it.